# .NET: Open files, which are embedded in a resource file

Tags: c#, .net

How can I open files, which are embedded in a resource file, like a file on the harddisk (with an absolute path) ?

Comment: What do you mean by open? Do you mean load the binary content?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Are you talking about accessing embedded  resources or ones on your harddisk?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose that you have the `test.xml` file embedded into the assembly. You could use the [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) method to obtain a stream pointing towards the contents:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.test.xml"))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

This way the contents of the file is read into memory. You can also store it to the harddisk and then access by absolute path but this might not be necessary as you already have the contents of the file.

Comment: You need to include the project's default namespace before the filename, not the project name.

Comment: If the file does not exist as an embedded resource, your 'stream' variable will be null. This will cause an exception when creating your StreamReader.