# Open embedded file in Windows program

Tags: c#, embed, revit-api

I put a file on my Resources in my C# program. I try to open it in a specific app but don't understand how.

I already see this: [.NET: Open files, which are embedded in a resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976180/net-open-files-which-are-embedded-in-a-resource-file)

and this: [Use embedded file from resources.resx in program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723049/use-embedded-file-from-resources-resx-in-program)

I need to open "TEST.rvt" (Autodesk Revit file), Which is an embedded resource, in Revit.exe

I don't want to copy the file to my system, so setting the `Copy to Output Directory` option is not possible.

Is it possible?

[image: This is my little program]

Comment: How do you want to open it? See the contents of the file? Open it with Revit? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Open it with Revit yes.

Comment: Alright, check this question: [c# open file with default application and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365984/c-sharp-open-file-with-default-application-and-parameters)

Comment: It doesn't work with EMBEDDED file.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609536/8873143) helps, even if its for a PDF

Comment: In the answers of this post Adam say "In order for this to work, the Visual Studio setting Copy to Output Directory has to be set to Copy Always for the PDF file."

I do not want this. I do not want to copy the file on Windows ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can read on many thread in the internet, it seem to be impossible. I will copy my .rvt in a temp folder and delete it just before using them.

To copy them I use the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031778/how-can-i-extract-a-file-from-an-embedded-resource-and-save-it-to-disk)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Revit so I don't know if this will work. But without setting `Copy to Output Directory` the following seems to work for a `.txt` file in Notepad.

```cs
string textFile = Properties.Resources.Testfile;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe"; // Set this to Revit.exe or whatever name it has
process.StartInfo.Arguments = textFile;
process.Start();
```

`Properties.Resources.Testfile` is the embedded `.txt` file in the project.

I don't know what a `.rvt` file looks like so I don't know if this will work correctly.

Comment: .rvt seem to be a byte[] so it will not work :/
https://prnt.sc/vto4dt

Comment: return me "cannot find the specified file" as you can see https://prnt.sc/vto75d I think convertion from byte[] to string is a bad idea :)

Comment: Just as a test, does `File.WriteAllBytes(Properties.Resources.TEST, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Properties.Resources.TEST));` work before doing the `Process` stuff? I think it does override the file thought :/ And maybe `Unicode` isn't the best idea here as well.

Comment: Maybe I can just give a byte[] instead of the string. Maybe Revit.exe can understand this type of argument instead of a string. I'm also trying your solution.